# Interpretation of "three coplanar lines intersect"

Tags: geometry

How should "three coplanar lines intersect" be drawn? Will they form something that looks like an asterisk? Or three lines that somehow form a triangle? Or either interpretation is acceptable?

Comment: Either interpretation is acceptable.

Comment: "three coplanar lines concur" (or, "are concurrent") would unambiguously indicate the asterisk case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk would be more clearly described by "three coplanar lines intersect in a point", and the triangle would be more clearly described by "three coplanar lines intersect pairwise". Without either of these clarifications, the statement is ambiguous and could be interpreted either way, depending on the context.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. 

- Case closed -

Comment: @user60623: That's what the checkmark is for -- if your question has been fully answered, you can click on the checkmark next to the answer that you want to accept as the best answer; this has the effect that the question is no longer marked as unanswered in the system and thus doesn't take up valuable space on the main page. It also gives $15$ points to the answer's author. If you just want to acknowledge an answer you find helpful but don't think it fully resolves the question, you can just upvote it with the up arrow next to it (which gives $10$ points to the author).